# Create interface for object or for action / behavior?

Tags: oop, architecture, interface, naming

When come to create an interface, do u create it based on behavior, follow the -able standard, e.g.

```
interface Comparable
interface Enumerable
interface Listable
interface Talkable
interface Thinkable
```

Or based on object, e.g.

```
interface Comparator
interface Enumerator
interface List
interface Human
```

And why?

**UPDATE**

This question is not about the naming convention (-able suffix or I- prefix). This is about the design intention of the interface, and the impact of it, in terms of:-

1. flexibility
2. complexity / simplicity
3. maintainability

For example, if I need to implement different features, by doing -able way, I can declare my class as

```
public class Man implements Talkable, Thinkable, Laughable
public class Woman implements Talkable, Thinkable, Laughable
```

On the other hand, if we create interface based on object, we can use it as

```
public class Man implements Human
public class Woman implements Human
```

And we can also use it for polymorphism purpose.

```
Human man = new Man();
```

Comment: The standards for this are largely language-specific, and sometimes subjective to the programmer and standards at an organization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interfaces are not about what a concrete class does. They are more about what the client needs, and what is substitutable in place of what the client needs. For example, instead of trying to extract an interface from a `Man` class, instead focus on one of the classes that use the `Man` class. What does it do? Perhaps it is a `Conversation` class that wants to make things talk to each other. If you gave it two `Man` classes, it could call `talk()` on them. But if you wanted it to be more flexible, you can abstract out the concept of what it does - makes things talk, and have it use a `Talkable` interface (for example). When you see a `Talkable` interface on this `Conversation` class, you shouldn't think "that is really a `Man`" but rather, "Where I see a `Talkable`, I can substitute anything that implements `Talkable`, whether it is a `Man`, `Woman`, `Parrot`, `Robot`, etc."

If I am unclear, there are good resources available on the subject. Check out Robert Martin's [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/dip.pdf), [Interface Segregation Principle](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/isp.pdf), and [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/lsp.pdf) articles for starters.

Answer (score 3):

An interface `Comparable` should be implemented by classes whose instances can be COMPARED; an interface `Comparator` (in languages that do any level of generic programming, probably `Comparator<T>`!-) should be implemented by classes whose instances can COMPARE OTHERS. Both usages have excellent use cases, essentially disjoint from each other; you seem to be missing this key semantic distinction.

Comment: the example I am using is not tied to any implementation of particular language (Java). The Comparable/Comparator interface are just one of the example, which might be used in C#, C++, Actionscript etc.

Comment: Nor is my answer Java-y, I'm just suggesting the `<T>` notation for genericity because it's widely used. My point's about *English*: an Enumerable *can be* enumerated, an Enumerator *performs* the enumerating; and so forth, for most transitive verbs. Very different semantics. Even intransitive verbs work similarly (typically with some preposition implied): a Laughable object is one that *can be* laughed AT (that's what the word MEANS!), a Laugher is a subject who laughs. It's subject vs (grammatical) direct object.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces were made to define the necessary behaviour of objects, and you can have a similar behaviour for multiple objects .. Like if you want to create the behaviour of humans, you can have the objects man and women, who share the same behaviours, but have some distinct functions / attributes. If you don't use interfaces this way, in this case you would have to create 2 interfaces for both human genders.

So, interfaces are related to the behaviour of objects.